# AttributeError: 'RandomForestClassifier' object has no attribute 'estimators_' when adding estimator to DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I am trying to store several estimators in a pandas DataFrame, and I keep running into this error:

> AttributeError: 'RandomForestClassifier' object has no attribute 'estimators_'

Initially, I though this was due to the fact that it was trying to copy the estimator to several rows, however, I was able to replicate the error with the following code:

```
pd.DataFrame({
    "foo" : "bar",
    "model" : RandomForestClassifier()
})
```

I also tried saving the estimator class in a dictionary and instantiating it in the dataFrame as seen below:

```
d = {"rf" : RandomForestClassifier}
pd.DataFrame({
    "foo" : "bar",
    "model" : d["rf"](random_state=100)
})
```

yet I still get the same error. So I'm thinking, if there is a solution for doing it as a single entry, then I'll be able to sclae that up. Does anyone have any ideas?

---

Edit to include stack trace:

```
  File "Local\Temp\ipykernel_27224\3809885946.py", line 7, in <cell line: 5>
    pd.DataFrame({
  File "Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 636, in __init__
    mgr = dict_to_mgr(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype, copy=copy, typ=manager)
  File "Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 502, in dict_to_mgr
    return arrays_to_mgr(arrays, columns, index, dtype=dtype, typ=typ, consolidate=copy)
  File "Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 120, in arrays_to_mgr
    index = _extract_index(arrays)
  File "Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 659, in _extract_index
    raw_lengths.append(len(val))
  File "Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\_base.py", line 195, in __len__
    return len(self.estimators_)
AttributeError: 'RandomForestClassifier' object has no attribute 'estimators_'
```

Comment: Please (always) provide the full error traceback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that pandas is trying to explode the values of your dictionary into values for multiple rows, for which it checks the `len` of each, and `RandomForestClassifier` defines a `__len__` method, as the number of fitted estimators (i.e. `len(estimators_)`).

In your one-row case, you can just wrap everything as singleton lists:

```py
pd.DataFrame({
    "foo": ["bar"],
    "model": [RandomForestClassifier()],
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is really bizzare,  it has to have something to do with the way a pandas DF instantiates.  As a work around, I dont get the same error when using pd.Series instead...Which you could then turn into a DF

```
ser = pd.Series({
    "foo" : "bar",
    "model" : RandomForestClassifier(),
})
df = pd.DataFrame(ser)
```